# Oracle Date Formatting Null date as 00/00/0000

Tags: oracle, null, date, formatting

How can I format the Null Dates in my Oracle SQL to 00/00/0000.
I am using NVL function but it doesn't recognize the 00/00/0000 as the date format.

Is there any Date Formatting available in Oracle SQL which formats null date to 00/00/0000

Comment: Why are you wanting to use 00/00/0000 instead of null?

Comment: very large or very small values can confuse the optimizer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do the to_char first and wrap it in the NVL.
For example,

```
select nvl(to_char(null, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '00-00-0000') from dual
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I didn't thought it was so easy to convert.!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to assign default values of null values of date:

```
SELECT id, NVL(start_date, to_date('20020101','YYYYMMDD')) FROM employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mty_containers mt  where terminal_id=1
and (
    in_date>=decode(to_date('','dd/mm/yyyy'),'',mt.in_date,to_date('','dd/mm/yyyy'))
     or  (case when '' is null  then nvl(to_char(in_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'N') End ='N' )
     )
and 
   (
     in_date<=decode(to_date('','dd/mm/yyyy'),'',mt.in_date,to_date('','dd/mm/yyyy'))
     or  (case when '' is null  then nvl(to_char(in_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'N') End ='N' )
   )
```

Comment: Date fillter when from  and to data is avialable then show only those records other wise all record will show

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).